# C++ const char* messes up the multiboot header

Tags: c++, operating-system, clang

This is weird.

So I'm trying to make a little kernel and I decided to use C++ for this. I did everything and I now have an (almost) working VGA Text Mode Driver. Why almost? Because whenever I pass the `write` method a `const char*` the multiboot header literally disappears.

And after a bit of fiddling i realized that ANY `const char*` use makes it go bonkers. Even just a variable.

The weird thing is that if I never create a `const char*` it just works. I can print individual characters too.

**Note**: I based on the [Bare Bones Tuturial on OSDev](https://wiki.osdev.org/Bare_Bones).

Here's the relevant code:

```
# Main.asm

MBALIGN equ 1 << 0
MEMINFO equ 1 << 1
FLAGS equ MBALIGN | MEMINFO
MAGIC equ 0x1BADB002
CHECKSUM equ -(MAGIC + FLAGS)

section .multiboot
align 4
    dd MAGIC
    dd FLAGS
    dd CHECKSUM

section .bss
align 16
    stack_bottom:
    resb 16384
    stack_top:

section .text
global _start:function (_start.end - _start)
_start:
    mov esp, stack_top

    extern kernel_main
    call kernel_main

    cli

.hang: hlt
    jmp .hang

.end:
```

```
// Main.cpp
void init() {
    Drivers::VGA vga;
    vga.putc('h');
    vga.write("hello", 5);
}

extern "C" void kernel_main() {
    init();
}
```

```
// Part of VGA.cpp
void VGA::write(const char* data, size_t size) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i += 1) {
            s_buffer[i] = vga_entry(data[i], _color);
        }
}

[...]

u16 VGA::vga_entry(unsigned char c, u8 color) {
        return (u16)c | (u16)color << 8;
}
```

```
# Linker.ld

ENTRY(_start)

SECTIONS {
    . = 1M;

    .text : ALIGN(4K) {
        KEEP(*(.multiboot))
        *(.text)
    }

    .rodata : ALIGN(4K) {
        *(.rodata)
    }

    .data : ALIGN(4K) {
        *(.data)
    }

    .bss : ALIGN(4K) {
        *(COMMON)
        *(.bss)
    }
}
```

Compiler Options: `-target i686-pc-elf -c -IKernel -ffreestanding -nostdlib++ -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fno-stack-protector -m32 -fno-use-cxa-atexit`

Toolchain: Clang, Nasm and ld.lld

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but which part of the "relevant code" actually implements `write`? What code gets executed when `vga.write("hello", 5)` is called? What's the definition of the class `Drivers::VGA`?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I just added it. I didn't add it at first since I thought it isn't really relevant, since even just creating a variable of type `const char*` messes it up

Comment: Hmm. The only thing unusual about string literals is that they go into `.rodata` section. Maybe somehow this section doesn't make it into the final binary? It seems like it should though. Sorry, that's the extent of my knowledge.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Ok, using readelf I saw that .rodata would go before .text (which contains .multiboot). This isn't how it should be, right? Without any string literal in the code .rodata goes away

Comment: @IgorTandetnik nevermind, I posted an answer

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `ld.lld` has a bug(?) or something. It put the rodata section before text, so the multiboot header wouldn't be visible.

Here's the output of `readelf -S Kernel` with `ld.lld`

```
Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Addr     Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  [ 0]                   NULL            00000000 000000 000000 00      0   0  0
  [ 1] .rodata.str1.1    PROGBITS        00100000 001000 000001 01 AMS  0   0  1
  [ 2] .text             PROGBITS        00101000 002000 0002fe 00  AX  0   0 4096
  [ 3] .data             PROGBITS        00102000 003000 000004 00  WA  0   0 4096
  [ 4] .bss              NOBITS          00103000 003004 004000 00  WA  0   0 4096
  [ 5] .comment          PROGBITS        00000000 003004 000029 01  MS  0   0  1
  [ 6] .symtab           SYMTAB          00000000 003030 0001a0 10      8  14  4
  [ 7] .shstrtab         STRTAB          00000000 0031d0 000044 00      0   0  1
  [ 8] .strtab           STRTAB          00000000 003214 00018f 00      0   0  1
```

And here's the output with system's `ld` (GNU)

```
Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Addr     Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  [ 0]                   NULL            00000000 000000 000000 00      0   0  0
  [ 1] .text             PROGBITS        00100000 001000 0002fe 00  AX  0   0 4096
  [ 2] .rodata.str1.1    PROGBITS        001002fe 0012fe 000001 01 AMS  0   0  1
  [ 3] .data             PROGBITS        00101000 002000 000004 00  WA  0   0 4096
  [ 4] .bss              NOBITS          00102000 002004 004000 00  WA  0   0 4096
  [ 5] .comment          PROGBITS        00000000 002004 000015 01  MS  0   0  1
  [ 6] .symtab           SYMTAB          00000000 00201c 0001f0 10      7  19  4
  [ 7] .strtab           STRTAB          00000000 00220c 00018f 00      0   0  1
  [ 8] .shstrtab         STRTAB          00000000 00239b 000044 00      0   0  1
```